# Python urllib requesting multiple times

Tags: python, urllib

I've written the following python code which connects to a URL to get data using json. However, when my server logs these requests, they are being made twice each time.

I am assuming it has something to do with the fact that it's first using `try` and then re-requesting the URL if the try method is met. Any suggestions on how I can make this so that it's only sending the request to the server once? Thanks

```
            import json
            import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse

            remoteURL = "http://192.168.0.29/" + "?id=" + id
            json_obj = urllib.request.urlopen(remoteURL)


            try:
                with urllib.request.urlopen(remoteURL) as response:
                    if response.read(1):
                        string = json_obj.read().decode('utf-8')
                        json_obj = json.loads(string)
                        responseName = json_obj['Name']
                        print(responseName)
                    else:
                        print("Error")
            except:
                print("URL Failed")
```

Comment: Ofcourse it makes the call twice. You call `urlopen(remoteURL)` twice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First request:

```
json_obj = urllib.request.urlopen(remoteURL)
```

Second request:

```
with urllib.request.urlopen(remoteURL) as response:
```